# ssl(certificate based authentication) complete working and understanding in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I am trying to understand the concept of ssl in wp7.

I learnt that public key is installed in the phone. 
And how the private key will synchronize with the public key? 
Is there any code needed?

In my scenario is that i have a username and password. 
and for client authentication i want this ssl communication.

How to implement this ssl concept for this scenario? 
And i dont want to disturb user experience too.

Answer (score 2):

Short anwer: you cannot add trusted certificates to the phone and you cannot make HTTPS connections to servers with untrusted certificates.

Long answer

You can install a custom certificate on the phone by [emailing it to yourself](http://pocketnow.com/windows-phone/how-to-install-custom-ssl-certificates-on-wp7) and opening the attachment on the phone. However, you'll have to do it on the emulator everytime it starts and you can't ask users of your application to do it (you'll very likely be rejected from the marketplace).

Comment: You can also browse to it, if you happen to be using fiddler.

Comment: @curiosity - The answer is to obtain/purchase an SSL certificate from a [certificate authority supported by Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150(v=VS.92).aspx)

Comment: @curiosity - Do you doubt that officially supported certificate authorities will work? You'd need to bring that up with Microsoft. To be clear, if you use a supported certificate authority _on the server_ you won't need to still anything but your application on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following bog:

> [WP7CertInstaller 1.0.0.0 Explained](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2011/01/19/wp7certinstaller-1-0-0-0-explained.aspx)